# How to turn on and find connection logging for SMB Windows file sharing server log in macOS 12 (Monterey)+?

Tags: macos, network, monterey, smb, logs

Having some trouble finding out if a Windows client is actually hitting a macOS 12 file server. It seems like they are, but I can't seem to find any connection / access logs that indicate such things on macOS now. Where are these stored or does this function have to be turned on and, if so, then where would I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears macOS no longer has an actual log file for the SMB server. The `smbd` process logs can be found in `Console.app` by doing a search for "PROCESS: smbd" as follows in the top right side of `Console.app`:

[image: console filter of smbd]

This will allow you to see all connection attempts and other log-related items for the `smbd` SMB Windows sharing server on macOS.